# Python: Correct way to handle chain exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to look for a better way to handle the following exception,

```
def fun(i, j, k, l):
    try:
        do_something_1(i)
    except TimeoutException as f:
        try:
            do_something_2(j)
        except TimeoutExeption as e:
            try:
                do_something_3(k)
            except TimeoutExeption as e:
                try:
                    do_something_4(l)
                except TimeoutExeption as e:
                    raise Exception
```

The basic idea is to try something, if it doesn't work, try next thing and so on until it gets what it wants or fails. But it has to follow the order of execution.

How can I make it better?

Comment: Don't catch bare Exception, because you won't know exactly what raised the exception.

Comment: If every function has the same parameters, then you could iterate over a collection of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably use a loop?

```
def fun(i):
    errors = []
    things_to_try = (thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4)
    for thing in things_to_try:
        try:
            thing(i)
        except Exception as e:
            errors.append(e)
        else:
            break
    else:
        raise Exception("Failed: %s" % errors)
```

Comment: You probably want to format them up a bit better than just `%s`, but that's cosmetic

Answer (score 2):

Using a for loop:

```py
for fct in [do_something_1, do_something_2, do_something_3]:
    try:
        fct(i)
        break
    except Exception:
        continue
else:
    raise Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return` statements to exit the function as early as possible, to avoid the nesting. Use `pass` as an empty statement to let the execution continue below, if there is nothing else to do in case of an exception.

```
def fun(i):
    try:
        do_something_1(i)
        return
    except TimeoutException as f:
        pass

    try:
        do_something_2(i)
        return
    except TimeoutExeption as e:
        pass

    try:
        do_something_3(i)
        return
    except TimeoutExeption as e:
        pass

    try:
        do_something_4(i)
        return
    except TimeoutException as e:
        raise Exception
```

For the final step, the `return` is not really necessary, but you can keep it for consistency, and to avoid a mistake in case you add more steps below later.

Answer (score 1):

A function is a first class object in Python, so you could rewrite you code:

```
def fun(i):
    e = None     # to be able to re-raise the last exception
    for f in (do_something_1, do_something_2, do_something_3,
              do_something_4, do_something_5):
        try:
            return f(i)
        except (TimeoutException as exc):
            e = exc     # actually stores the last raised exception
    else:
        raise e         # re-raise last exception
```